# Android Studio 2.1 mis-checking conditions

Tags: android, android-studio

Updated Android Studio to 2.1 and finding big issues. Though I am not sure if I am missing something or the Android Studio. It is not executing all lines sometimes, even entering code block in a `if` statement though the conditions should return `false`. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Do you have a solution?

Comment: I think this is happening because, the code that you are debugging in your device/emulator is different from the code displayed in the editor. Reinstall the app and try again.

Comment: No. Restarting my mac does fix this. So, each time I change any variable I have to restart

Comment: No. I don't think so. But if it is required, then god bless us all.